# How to see a value with ? in for loop

Tags: cmd

The following batch

```
set VAR=A ?B C? D
for %%i in (%VAR%) do echo [%%i]
```

prints out:

```
[A]
[D]
```

Is there any way (escape sequence etc.) to see what I had expected:

```
[A]
[?B]
[C?]
[D]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch file: Escape questionmark in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852631/batch-file-escape-questionmark-in-for-loop)

Comment: it's a duplicate but the answer of Magoo is new and useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set VAR=A ?B C? D
CALL :show %var%
GOTO :EOF

:show
SET $=%1
IF DEFINED $ ECHO %1&shift&GOTO show
GOTO :eof
```

Here's a way...