# Why can't you use a question mark in a batch for loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

## Preface

While writing a separate piece of code, I encountered a problem with question marks in for loops. As shown below, the question mark is not accessed in the for loop.

Batch file:

```
@echo off

for %%x in (the, quick, ?, brown, fox) do (
    echo %%x
)
```

Output:

```
the
quick
brown
fox
```

This also does not work in the CMD (using `%x` instead of `%%x`), or when using `""`, `[]`, `^`, `\`, `%` or other common methods of character escaping.

Using a counter variable to determine the number of times the code within the parentheses was accessed only results in a total count of 4, meaning it is clearly not a problem with the `echo` command.

---

## Question

Why doesn't a question mark work in a standard for loop, and how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: Many characters have special meaning to the cmd interpreter. To use them as literals, you need to escape them. The ^ is the normal escape character. To escape a percent symbol you double the percent symbol.

Comment: @Squashman Thanks for the response. As I alluded to in the end of my preface, I had tried using `^`, `%` and even ``\``, of which I previously had known to work for most character escapes. However, it hadn't worked with the question mark in a for loop, hence the curiosity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file: Escape questionmark in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852631/batch-file-escape-questionmark-in-for-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `?` will be expanded into a list of filenames one character long. The "naked" `for` is using that list as a list of *filenames.*

If you run the following commands, you'll see this in action:

```
c:\> echo xx >a
c:\> echo xx >b
c:\> for %i in (1, ?) do echo %x
1
a
b
```

If you look at [Rob van der Woude's excellent scripting pages](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/), you'll see that the [`for` page](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) has options for processing command output, numbers and files - it's not really suited for arbitrary strings.

One way to get around that is to provide your *own* `for`-like command as shown in the following example:

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Call the callback function for each argument.
    set escapee=/
    call :doFor :processEach 1 2 ? 4 5
    echo.Escapee was %escapee%

    rem Execute simple command for each argument.
    call :doFor echo 6 7 ? 9 10

    endlocal
    goto :eof

:processEach
    set escapee=%escapee%%1/
    goto :eof

:doFor
    setlocal

    rem Get action.
    set cbAction=%1
    shift

:dfloop
    rem Process each argument with callback or command.
    if not "%1" == "" (
        call %cbAction% %1
        shift
        goto :dfloop
    )
    endlocal&&set escapee=%escapee%
    goto :eof
```

This provides a single functions which can handle both callbacks and simple commands. For more complex commands, provide a callback function and it will get called with each argument in turn. The callback function can be arbitrarily complex but keep in mind that, because it's operating within a `setlocal`, changes to environment variables cannot escape back to the caller.

As a way around this, it allows *one* variable, `escapee`, to escape the scope - you could also add more if needed.

For simple commands (like `echo`) where you just need the argument placed at the end, you do the same thing. It doesn't need a callback function but it's restricted to very simple scenarios.

Also keep in mind that, although this seems like a lot of code, the vast majority of it only needs to exist in one place. To use it, you simply need a one-liner like the sample:

```
call :doFor echo my hovercraft is full of eels
```

Also keep in mind that there may be *other* characters that do not fare well, even with this scheme. It solves the `?` issue but others may still cause problems. I suspect that this would be an ideal opportunity to add PowerShell to your CV, for example, a command that's almost `bash`-like in it's elegance and zen-ness:

```
PShell> foreach ($item in @("1", "?", "3", "4")) { echo $item }
1
?
3
4
```

Answer (score 3):

You could switch to `FOR /F`.
But FOR /F is used to process multiple lines to split them into tokens.
In your case you don't need multiple tokens, you need one loop per item.

That can be done by splitting the items with linefeeds.
I'm using `#` as item delimiter, but you are free to use any other character

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set \n=^
%=EMPTY=%
)

set "itemList=the#quick#?#brown#fox"
for %%L in ("!\n!") DO (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%x in ("!itemList:#=%%~L!") DO echo - %%x -
)
```

Output:

```
- the -
- quick -
- ? -
- brown -
- fox -
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been coding with batch many years, and I'm suprised to realize this issue until now!

I found another way to deal with this problem. May be somebody prefers it, like me.

In my particularly case, I'm using the FOR LOOP to get some named arguments of the current function. This is what I did:

```
:SomeFunct
rem Replace ?
set "args=%*"
set "args=%args:?=`%"

rem Iterate args
for %%p in (%args%) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=: " %%a in ("%%~p") do (
        rem Get and store values
        if /i "%%~a" equ "/a" set "argA=%%~b"
        if /i "%%~a" equ "/b" set "argB=%%~b"
        if /i "%%~a" equ "/c" set "argC=%%~b"
    )
)

rem Restore ?
if defined argA set "argA=%argA:`=?%"
if defined argB set "argB=%argB:`=?%"
if defined argC set "argC=%argC:`=?%"

rem I use the args
rem ...

rem Return
goto:eof
```

I call the function like this:

```
rem Calling example
call:SomeFunct "/a:Is there" "/b:a question mark" "/c in the arguments?"
```